# Class Instance Release Order?

Tags: objective-c, memory

This is probably a pretty basic question, but just something that I wanted to make sure I had right in my head. When I release the class instance "newPlanet_001" what is the order of  disposal, Am I right in assuming that if the retain count of the object is 1 prior to the release that the instances dealloc method is called first (to release the instance variable "planetName") before continuing to release the class instance as a whole?

(i.e.)

```
// CLASS
@interface PlanetClass : NSObject {
    NSString *planetName;
}
- (NSString *)planetName;
- (void)setPlanetName:(NSString *)newPlanetName;
@end

// MAIN
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    PlanetClass *newPlanet_001;
    newPlanet_001 = [[PlanetClass alloc] init];
    [newPlanet release];
}

// DEALLOC
- (void)dealloc {
    [planetName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

cheers -gary-

Comment: Do not ever design or implement Objective-C code based on the value of absolute retain counts.  Relative is fine;  if you retain, you must release.  Relying on the retain count to be a certain value or make a certain transition is the path to madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The planetName object is released BEFORE the newPlanet_001 instance.

Answer (score 3):

`-[NSObject release]` calls `-dealloc` if the retain count is zero. This allows the object to cleanup any objects it owns before calling `[super dealloc]` to do the actual deallocation.

If implemented properly, an object will release any objects it owns before calling the super (this them to get deallocated if their retain count is also zero).

<sub>An object owns another if it calls `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` on it.</sub>